# How to request file with array name of input file?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Just wondering why I can't get value of array name from input type file.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="collateral_photo[]" id="collateral_photo" class="default"/>
```

The name of this input file is an array.

**PHP Laravel**

```
return Request::file('collateral_photo');
```

The return result is [{}]

What I want right now just how to get value from this input file with array name.

Please, please help me out.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: You may have forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Comment: I do input this enctype already.

Comment: Don't use id use name instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use the below code, since the name attribute is an array

```
$files = Request::file('collateral_photo');
return $files[0];
```

or if you want second file

```
return $files[1];

//if you want to access second file and so on
```

you need to access the file with array index specified.

If you want to return the whole files array itself then use

```
return $files
```

Comment: @Sourabh...If I use this, the return result get nothing. :(

Comment: what is the result of var_dump() ?

Comment: surly if I return with specified offset like return $files[0], it show me the value. But if I try with return $files, it give me this [{}].

Comment: i do not see any reason for it return [{}], can you post the code in your question where you are accessing it? Might be you are accessing it in a wrong manner

Comment: Ohhh...I solved it now. I used return with specified offset to loop the value.
Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 4):

And going one step further we can work with multiple-level-arrays like so:

```
<input name="channel[1][file]" type="file">
<input name="channel[2][file]" type="file">
```

in laravel you would need a structure

```
$files = $request->file('channel');
$file1 = $files[1]['file'];
$file2 = $files[2]['file'];
```

Comment: It works fine for me! in conjunction with this check function  $request->hasFile("channel.1.file")

Answer (score 3):

If it is an array of files do:

```
$request()->file($fieldName)[$key]->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: remove "()" on request and working,  `$request->file($fieldName)[$key]->getClientOriginalName();`